# Add or update an attribute in a tag using Beautiful Soup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-escape-characters

given the code below:

```py
    html_code = '<table id="definition-table"><tbody><tr><td>' \
                '<p><b><i><span class="lang">*Reporter&#39;s name:</span></i></b></p>' \
                '</td><td>John Doe</td></tr></tbody></table>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "lang"}):
        tag_to_replace = str(tag)
        key = generate_key_from_name(tag.string)
        tag['key'] = key
        new_tag = str(tag)
        html_code.replace(tag_to_replace, new_tag)
```

So basically I need to find all `span` tags in the html code with `class="lang"` attribute, and add/update an attribute key with a value given by the function `generate_key_from_name`, which returns a simple string. This code used to work well until I got to the example below, because Beautiful Soup is replacing `&#39;` with the corresponding single quote, so the replace call at the end does not find the string to replace (it searches for `*Reporter's name:` instead of `*Reporter&#39;s name:`. I have tried with `tag.replace_with(new_tag)` but having `<span class="lang">` multiple times in the html code, I have no clue how to find the one I need to replace.

Anyone can improve my code so it works regardless the html code uses `*Reporter&#39;s name:` or `*Reporter's name:`? (i.e. using a replace function from Beautiful Soup rather than string replace)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`soup` is updated when you do `tag['key'] = key`, so there is no need to carry out a string replace—beautifulsoup is designed so that you just make changes to the BeautifulSoup object directly and then export the updated string at the end.

This also makes the code much shorter. Since you didn't provide the `generate_key_from_name` function, I've just created a dummy function that always returns `"Reporter's name"` for the code below.

```
def generate_key_from_name(input_str):

    return "Reporter's name"


html_code = '<table id="definition-table"><tbody><tr><td>' \
            '<p><b><i><span class="lang">*Reporter&#39;s name:</span></i></b></p>' \
            '</td><td>John Doe</td></tr></tbody></table>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "lang"}):
    key = generate_key_from_name(tag.string)
    tag['key'] = key
str(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
'<table id="definition-table"><tbody><tr><td><p><b><i><span class="lang" key="Reporter\'s name">*Reporter\'s name:</span></i></b></p></td><td>John Doe</td></tr></tbody></table>'
```

Alternatively you can call `soup.prettify()` instead of `str(soup)` to get:

```
<table id="definition-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <p>
     <b>
      <i>
       <span class="lang" key="Reporter's name">
        *Reporter's name:
       </span>
      </i>
     </b>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td>
    John Doe
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps—please let me know if there's something I'm missing!